# Count total number of rows where this.row is related with rows in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two simple tables, `parents` and `children`. I am trying to count the number of parents who have at least one child.

```
create table People(
    id integer unique,
    name varchar(120),
    primary key (id)
);

create table children(
    id integer unique,
    name varchar(120),
    parentId integer,
    primary key(id),
    foreign key (parentId) references People(id)
);
```

This is the code I tried but it gives me the total number of children instead:

```
select count(*)
from (people p join children ch on ch.parentid = p.id)
having count(ch.id) > 0;
```

Comment: You can only use HAVING clause when you use GROUP BY

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgres? These are different RDBMS, with vendor specificities. I removed the conflicting tags, please add back the relevant one.

Comment: @GMB i am using Postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to count the number of parents who have at least one children.

This should be as simple as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM people p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM children c WHERE c.parentid = p.id)
```

Using `EXISTS` is usually the most efficient way to check that something, well, exists.

Answer (score 1):

You're close. You just need to make the check for children on a per-parent basis:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS parents_with_children
FROM (SELECT p.name, COUNT(c.id) AS num_children
      FROM people p
      JOIN children c ON c.parentid = p.id
      GROUP BY p.name
      HAVING COUNT(c.id) > 0) p
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rj8LLVWRGiqVsiVrXbXWeM/1)

Comment: I get an error for this, column "num_children" does not exist, tbh i had similar solution myself and got similar error, and i could not debug it. Sorry for my noob questions.

Comment: @SachihiroTakamori did you use a `HAVING` or a `WHERE` clause? You can't use an alias in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @SachihiroTakamori I've corrected a minor error in the query, and added a demo of it working.

Comment: i corrected too,  adding the alias in the end but i still get the error, does it have to do because I am running postgres?

Comment: @SachihiroTakamori ah... when I answered the question it was tagged MySQL... I've updated the query so it will work on PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(p.*)
from people p inner join children ch
     on ch.parentid = p.id
```

Comment: Would you add some explanation, please ?

Answer (score 0):

With EXISTS:

```
select count(distinct p.id) counter from people p
where exists (
  select 1 from children
  where parentid = p.id
)
```

or even **better**:

```
select count(distinct parentid) counter 
from children
```

because all the info you need is in the table `children`, so just count the `distinct` values in column `parentid`

Comment: What does select 1 from children means?

Comment: What matters here is EXISTS. If there is at least 1 row returned then the condition is true. Select 1 could be select 0 or select * it does not matter as long as 1 row is returned.

Comment: Read more here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*),p.*
FROM People p JOIN children c ON c.parnetId=p.id
WHERE NOT c.parnetId IS NULL 
GROUP BY (p.id)
```

(no need for having since it only joins existing children anyways)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this,

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT children.parentid)
FROM People 
INNER JOIN children 
ON children.parentid = people.id;
```